# Binding data to D3 bubble nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am missing a step or two to get my data bound to the nodes I am creating for a d3 bubble chart. I can see the the nodes have been created in my svg and some of the data has been bound to the nodes (e.g. the title)

```
<body>
<svg class="bubble" width="960" height="960">
<g class="node" transform="translate(undefined,undefined)">
<title>mip: 24</title>
<circle style="fill: rgb(49, 130, 189);">
</g>
<g class="node" transform="translate(undefined,undefined)">
<title>theft: 558</title>
<circle style="fill: rgb(107, 174, 214);">
</g>
<g class="node" transform="translate(undefined,undefined)">
<g class="node" transform="translate(undefined,undefined)">
<g class="node" transform="translate(undefined,undefined)">
<g class="node" transform="translate(undefined,undefined)">
</svg>
</body>
```

I am missing something at the point where the actual values from my data are bound to the nodes, defining the circles and their dimensions.

I feel like I am close but don't quite understand how data is bound in D3.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jsc2q/6/) is a fiddle showing what I have so far

Answer (score 0):

You're already most of the way there. In your example, the functions supplied to the D3 methods all take an argument: `d`. `d` (or whatever you choose to call it) will be the data object that D3 is rendering an SVG for. `this` will be a reference to the SVG element itself, to which that data is bound.

Here's a [revised fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsc2q/7/), where the radius of your circles is bound to d.totalCrimes, and they render appropriately, I think.

Comment: That looks close but something is still hanging up when the transform is bound to the <g class"nodes"> elements. I believe that is why all the bubbles are drawing over one another in your fiddle

Comment: Since my data was already flattened I had to bind it differently than in the fiddle you sent along. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/jsc2q/8/

Comment: I guess I still don't understand what you don't understand. Can you clarify your question with an edit? What are you trying to accomplish that you still don't know how to accomplish? (And what changed in your latest fiddle, and how does that relate to your problem?)

Comment: In your fiddle the x,y values were never bound to the <g> elements, just the radius. Check out my recent fiddle where you can see the transform values bound

Comment: Where are the x,y values? Your model only has two properties on it, neither of which resemble coordinates. You are attempting to assign x&y to the <g> elements in `.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })`, but where are those supposed to be referenced from? (Or how would you like to calculate them?)

Comment: you can see them bound in my recent fiddle as .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })

Comment: Right. That's the code I just copied, and all it does is assign the values of those properties as the x and y coordinates of the SVG element in the DOM. But what's the *source* of that data? Nowhere do you define properties called x and y on your data model. You only have 'crimeType' and 'totalCrimes' on each data object. Where is the position data supposed to be coming from?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40643/discussion-between-snowgage-and-xmlilley)